# Issues communicating PoKeys57CNC and Mach4 running on Windows 11 Home PC in Custom Shell Kiosk Mode

Tags: cnc, communication

**Some background Information**

I am using a Windows 11 Home PC to control a plasma cutting machine. The windows 11 machine uses Mach4 as the interface for controlling the plasma cutter and a PoKeys57CNC as the control board for the CNC.

**The PC stuff**

I am trying to create a sort of single app mode for the PC so that when I sign in to a specific user account, only Mach4 will run, and no other app. I have succesfully managed to create this Kiosk Mode by modifying registry entries, such as:

- **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon [Shell]**
  Sets which application gets loaded on sign in, this is set to `explorer.exe` by default.
- **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer [NoViewContextMenu]**
  Disabled right clicking when file explorer is open.
- **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer [NoTrayContextMenu]**
  Disabled right clicking on the windows start menu (I think).
- **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer [NoViewOnDrive]**
  Disabled access to certain drive letters on Windows, in my case I set it to disable access to all Drives, exclusing the Z drive. In another script I then create a virtual drive (using `subst`) that is connected to a specific folder and make it the Z drive.
  *This causes issues so I haven't really been using it, but I thought I would include it just because.*
- **HKCU\Console\%%Startup [DelegationConsole]**
  Changes the default terminal to use Windows Console Host instead of Windows Terminal.
- **HKCU\Console\%%Startup [DelegationTerminal]**
  Changes the default terminal to use Windows Console Host instead of Windows Terminal.
- **HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\opennewwindow\command [Default]**
  Sets the default open location for windows explorer. I set this to be the Z drive.
- **HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\opennewwindow\command [DelegateExecute]**
  Does something that I can't remember right now.
- **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System [DisableTaskMgr]**
  As it says, this disables task manager access when signed (so that nobody just disables the Kiosk Mode).
- **HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\URLBlocklist [1]**
  Disabled all URLs on Microsoft Edge.

This has resulted in a working Kiosk mode, but produces issues with the Mach4 connection to PoKeys. In the Shell entry I have a custom powershell script that loads on every sign in and which dictates what gets runs while the user is signed in.

To elaborate, this script currently changes the default login application from `explorer.exe` on Windows to my own custom script which loads Mach4 (my application of choice). This script prevents the user from accessing anything other than Mach4, and (as far as I'm aware) does not prevent any services or other base windows processes from running. Nonetheless, windows explorer is an important process to the windows architecture and it probably performs some task on login (that my script doesn't) which the software needs to operate correctly.

In this case, my script basically creates the virtual Z drive (using `subst`), and starts the Mach4 application. Lastly, when Mach4 closes it signs out of the user account.

I have tried to figure out what the issue could be and have found a few interesting things that might be able to allow someone more knowledgeable than me to figure it out as I haven't managed it yet.

1. It works on the main user account (which is an administrator account) with no issues.
2. It works on the kiosk account when the registry entries are not all set (I think the only registry entry that affects this is the first one which changes the Windows shell to something else.
3. When in the kiosk user account with all the registry entries loaded, if I  sign in (which loads Mach4) and then out 3 times, and then sign in one more time. The connection gets made and it works perfectly.
4. I have included in the sign-in shell script, some code that essentially closes and opens Mach4 4 times and then opens it a final time for actually use. This did not work for solving the problem which implies that it is the process of signing out and then in again that fixes the problem.

Comment: May be more suited to [PowerUser SE](https://superuser.com/). Try asking there if no reply is obtained here.

Comment: I posted it there, too. I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Figure out your application's dependencies.  You have likely shut off a service that your application needs.  Why not just give your application highest priority and dedicated cores?  You can then also experiment with shutting off services and the like and test what breaks it.  Alao mind that multiple users may be logged in at once

Comment: @Abel I was hoping that someone would be able to help figure out what that service could be, because it is difficult to test this out on the plasma machine due to it being in use. I have been reading through the documentation to see if there might be something in there that could advise me on the issue, but the only thing that I have found so far is that PoKeys uses Windows drivers to communicate with the control board, which shouldn't cause any issues because windows loads drivers on startup and not on sign in.

Comment: @Abel How does the highest priority and CPU affinity prevent access to other applications on Windows? I could maybe assign Mach4 top priority to all cores, but that doesn't sound like a great way to get past the problem. I only read up on processor affinity and priority now, so maybe I just don't understand it enough to understand what you are saying.

Comment: Unclear that what you want to do is prevent access.  If that is all, most kiosks do not turn off services (that's something people looking for more deterministic computation do).  They (1) trap a user in an application.  If the user finds an exploit to drop out or prevent application from starting, they end up in (2) an account with very limited permissions. If they manage to change something, then (3) all changes get wiped on reboot with everything loaded from a fresh image.

Comment: @Abel, sorry I didn't realise that my question was unclear, I'll fix that. To explain, at the moment, the user is blocked from accessing any application other than the selected one (Mach4) by making windows run Mach4 when logging in rather than the explorer process which gives you access to all of Windows' beautiful UI. It should not be disrupting any services, and the fact that the software works after opening and closing four times implies that it might not even be that a service is blocked. My current guess is that there is a service whose startup is delayed due to explorer not opening.